# Static or readonly modifier for field initialization

Tags: c#

Have a class:

```
class MyClass
{
   private static TimeSpan myField = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       // usage of field
   }
}
```

myField field initilizes inline. What modifier should I choose for it, static (as above) or readonly?

Comment: They mean completely different things. You should learn what each means, and decide based on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know what each means. But in this case I doubt. I want two things: 1) initialization should take place only once; 2) assigned value should not be modified.

Comment: in 1) I mean "only ones" for all instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# previous to 6.0 you would implement a `static readonly` field wrapped by a `static` property.

BTW, In C# 6.0 and above, this can be simplified to:

```
class MyClass
{
   // A read-only property that can only be set with a property initializer
   // or in a static constructor
   private static TimeSpan MyProperty { get; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       // usage of field
   }
}
```

...which implements a backing `static readonly` field during compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

`static` - it means it belongs to class and not instance.

`readonly` - it means that once it's defined - it can't be changed.

`const` - just inline constant like `#define` in C language.

Those are different things, you can't compare them.

ADD. Only primitive type can be `const`. In your case `static readonly`.

Comment: `TimeSpan` cannot be `const`. Only primitive types (numbers, strings, etc) can be const.